# Metadata API support for Approval Processes?

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api, workbench

EDIT:

I have search online and could not find any resource that talks about how to get metadata for Approval Process

I know that the approval process stores in the ProcessDefinition object but what I'm trying to find is the `Entry Criteria` that user have selected for the Approval Process how do I get this information in metadata api (workbench)

Here is the screen shot for ref:

[image]
EDIT END

I'm trying to execute the following rest explorer in Workbench and getting this error, what I'm doing wrong here?

> /services/data/v40.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+ProcessDefinition
>
> INVALID_TYPE message: sObject type 'ProcessDefinition' 
>   is not
>   supported. errorCode: INVALID_TYPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you just want a normal SOQL query rather than a Tooling API query.

The following ran against the SOAP Partner API no problem.

```
Select Id, Name From ProcessDefinition
```

It also worked in the Developer Console, which means it was executed against the REST API.
[image]

> Request URL:https://foo-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/query/?q=Select%20Id%2C%20Name%20From%20ProcessDefinition&columns=true&_=111111111111

See also:

- [ProcessDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processdefinition.htm)

---

**Update for subsequent question**

To get the Entry Criteria for the approval process you will need to go to the Metadata API. See [`ApprovalProcess`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_approvalprocess.htm) and the associated `entryCriteria` of type [ApprovalEntryCriteria](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_approvalprocess.htm#ApprovalEntryCriteria).

Getting to that in Apex will require a bit of work. You could try the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). There is also the official [Apex Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2017/05/introducing-apex-metadata-api.html), but that doesn't have access to the approval processes yet (as at Summer '17). Try raising the use case in the [success community](https://success.salesforce.com/0F930000000PbSh) or as an idea.

Comment: I'm trying to get `Entry Criteria` for the approval process, how would you get that? and I'm aware of the ProcessDefinition object and other Process objects

Comment: @NickKahn Can you refine your question with your requirements. I read it as just needing to run the SOQL query.

Comment: go to the Metadata API? can you show me how would you do that in workbench rest explorer? I tried `/services/data/v40.0/process/approvals` but did not find any information

Comment: @NickKahn The Metadata API isn't available via REST. It is SOAP based. You want the migration>retrieve tab in Workbench. You will need to create a package.xml to retrieve the ApprovalProcess

Comment: can that be possible via REST API ?

Comment: @NickKahn No, it isn't currently possible.

Answer (score 1):

because `ProcessDefinition` is not the supported object in tooling API.

you can check for supported object list [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm).

Comment: So what will be the alternate, I need to find the `Entry Criteria` that user have selected for the Approval Process

Comment: @NickKahn as per some old post[https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yNYIAY] thats not possible. Let see what other community members say.

Comment: remove the last bracket, it will work

Comment: @NickKahn remove bracket from end.  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yNYIAY

Comment: I did search before I post my question here and I read that post as well so in that post it says  `You could try the metadata API to query'  do you know how?

Comment: @NickKahn might help check the answer. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000k9utIAA